# How to create a navbar similar to the Angular Material 2 website?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, navbar

I am trying to learn Material in combinaton with Angular so that I can later apply the Material Design pattern to my applications. After browsing around I found Material2 for Angular and installed it on my machine through NPM. The website describes all the components it has and I first tried to start with the navigation components. After fiddling around a bit I found out that the components were not responsive. After some research I found out that flex layout could make the components work in combination with Material2. One thing I noticed on the Material2 website was that when I narrow the browser down to mobile device sizes, it would change the navbar (which has a few buttons) to this:

[image]

I marked the three buttons with a red box (Components, CDK, Guides). This is what I want to recreate, but as far as I know, there are no navbar components for Material2. Altough the navbar has Material2 buttons in it:

[image]

I was wondering how they made this, what do I need to have in order to do this? Can it be build in Material2 or should I use something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

FlexLayout offers a [Responsive API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API), which lets you define different layout properties based on the media query, e.g.:

```
<div fxLayout='column' class="zero">

  <div fxFlex="33" [fxFlex.md]="box1Width" class="one" ></div>
  <div fxFlex="33" [fxLayout]="direction" fxLayout.md="row" class="two">

    <div fxFlex="22"    fxFlex.md="10px" fxHide.lg class="two_one"></div>
    <div fxFlex="205px" fxFlex.md="65" class="two_two"></div>
    <div fxFlex="30px"  fxFlex.md="25"   fxShow [fxHide.md]="hideBox" class="two_three"></div>

  </div>
  <div fxFlex class="three"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install FlexLayout through npm in your project.

Steps to install FlexLayout:

`npm install @angular/flex-layout –save`

or with yarn

`yarn add @angular/flex-layout`

And if you do not want to use FlexLayout, you can use Bootstrap4 & material design, refer 'https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/navigation/navbar/'

Comment: Unfortunately some of my desired components are behind a paywall @ mdbootstrap. I tried it out though and it works really good, do you know of a open source framework that uses bootstrap and material design?

Comment: Or a free Material theme for bootstrap for that matter.

Comment: you can use Semantic UI, and other suggested frameworks, please see whatever fits you, refer @mdbootstrap